# How to find every number in a row and store average in separate per-row variable

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, aix

I just started learning shell scripting.

I'm trying to read from a file structured like:

```
harddrive1 10 20 30 40
harddrive2 20 30 40 50
harddrive3 30 40 50 60
```

I want to save the average of each row in a separate variable somehow...there will only be 3 rows, 5 columns.
So my output would be:

```
hd_AVG1=20
hd_AVG2=35
hd_AVG3=45
```

How can I accomplish that?

EDIT: I need to save it in DIFFERENT variable so that i can call the variable...for example

```
if [[ $hd_AVG1 -eq 20 ]];
    then 
    do something...
elif [[ $hd_AVG2 -gt 40 ]];
    then
    do something...
fi
```

Comment: It would be cool to see what code you currently use to read such a file, if any. If you don't have no code, google first.

Comment: Depending what the "something" is, you may be going down the wrong path doing this in shell. Also, you're mixing shell styles/constructs using [[ with arithemtic expressions and with -gt etc. You should be using if (( hd_AVG1 > 40 )) etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bash script should do what you want. It calls `bc` to do the float arithmetics since bash cannot do it itself.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -a line ; do
    sum=0
    for ((i=1; i<${#line[@]}; i++)) ; do
        let sum+=line[i]
    done;
    hd[j++]=$(bc -l <<< "$sum/($i-1)")
done < input
echo ${hd[0]} ${hd[1]} ${hd[2]}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your code correctly, does this code saves row1 result to variable1, row2 result to variable 2 etc...?

Comment: Change `<=` to `<` and `($i-2)` to `($i-1)`; this avoids an unnecessary iteration of the loop in which `line[i]` is always a final null string.

Comment: No-one would seriously write a while loop in shell with calls to bc just to add a few numbers. See the awk solution posted by @guru.

Comment: You can replace all of the shell and bc stuff above with just **hd=($(awk '{print ($2+$3+$4+$5)/4}' input))**. See the answer I posted below.

Answer (score 6):

```
$ awk '{print $1"="($2+$3+$4+$5)/4}' file
harddrive1=25
harddrive2=35
harddrive3=45
```

Comment: it works fine but here is the problem....i want to save it as different variable hd1..not harddrive1

Comment: print "hd" NR "=" ($2+$3+$4+$5)/4

Comment: @EdMorton Morton ok, if I replace this, the unix displays info i want. However, when i do echo $hd1 i get harddrive1  echo $hd2 i get nothing... :(

Comment: You didn't say you needed to populate a SHELL variable. Most of the solutions you're getting populate awk, perl, etc. variables or just print what you want to stdout. You can stick "eval" before the awk command: eval awk '...' to set shell variables named hd1 etc.

Comment: ah sorry, this is my second time writing shell script :(

Answer (score 2):

With `Perl` (very portable):

```
perl -lane 'print $F[0] . "=" . ($F[1] + $F[2] + $F[3] + $F[4]) / 4' file.txt
```

Comment: this basically does same thing as Guru's answer, it doesn't save each row's result to variables that I can actually call and use :(

Comment: Seems like you don't do any effort to understand anything by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Using an array population trick I just learned from @steve:

```
$ cat file
harddrive1 10 20 30 40
harddrive2 20 30 40 50
harddrive3 30 40 50 60
$
$ hd_AVG=($(awk '{print ($2+$3+$4+$5)/4}' file))
$ echo "${hd_AVG[0]}"
25
$ echo "${hd_AVG[1]}"
35
$ echo "${hd_AVG[2]}"
45
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this with coreutils and sed:

```
. <(paste -d=                                                   \
      <(cut -d' ' -f1  infile                                 ) \
      <(cut -d' ' -f2- infile  | sed 's/$/ + + + 4 \/ p/' | dc) \
   )
echo $harddrive1 $harddrive2 $harddrive3
```

Output:

```
25 35 45
```

#### Explanation

The `<( )` notation runs the commands within and pipes their output through a fifo, so `paste` sees two pipes and columnates their output with `=` as their delimiter.

The second `cut` takes the numbers from the file, `sed` appends appropriate operators to the numbers and lets `dc` do the calculation. The input to `dc` looks like this:

```
cut -d' ' -f2- infile | sed 's/$/ + + + 4 \/ p/'
```

Output:

```
10 20 30 40 + + + 4 / p
20 30 40 50 + + + 4 / p
30 40 50 60 + + + 4 / p
```

`dc` is a reverse polish calculator; it supports arbitrary precision, but needs to be told to use decimals. This will make `dc` use two decimals:

```
cut -d' ' -f2- dims | sed 's/^/2k/; s/$/ + + + 4 \/ p/'
```

The whole command is also wrapped in `<( )` and sourced with `.`, i.e. the variables will be available in the current environment.